# Table goes over border of page

Tags: tables

I have the following latex table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
{\bf Indicator}                                                                     & {\bf Source}                                                                                                               & {\bf Time Period} & {\bf Type} \\ \hline
Dividend Yield                                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Short-term interest rates                                                           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
slope of the yield curve                                                            & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
interest rate spread(difference between the long-term and short-term interest rate) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Property Rents                                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
property yields                                                                     & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
GDP                                                                                 & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Lagging    \\ \hline
varEmployment and money supply                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
the three month Treasury Bill rate (TBIL)                                           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
the yield on 20-year gilts (GY20)                                                   & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
narrow money supply (M0)                                                            & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
broad money supply (M4) and the price on the FTSE 100 share index (SP100)           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
car registrations (CAR)                                                             & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
volume of retail sales (RS) and jobs vacancies (JOBV).                              & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Space market index                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
exports/import                                                                      & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
metropolitan area leading economic index                                            & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
job advertisements                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
the yield curve                                                                     & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
trade internationally currency exchange                                             & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
house starts                                                                        & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
average weekly                                                                      & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
hours in manufacturing                                                              & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
construction costs                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
construction activity                                                               & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Gilt yields                                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Car registrations                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Net lending to consumers                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Export orders                                                                       & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Volume of expected output                                                           & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Financial Surplus Deficit                                                           & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Consumer confidence                                                                 & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Stock of finished goods                                                             & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Real money supply                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Changes in inventories                                                              & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Consumer credit                                                                     & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Personal disposable income                                                          & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Industrial production                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Unit labour costs                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Gross trading profits                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
House building starts                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Yield curve                                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Manufacturing investment                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Real money supply                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Press recruitment ads.                                                              & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Private to total credit                                                             & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
New orders in manufacturing                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
FT All Share price Index                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Manufacturing employment                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Retail sales                                                                        & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Sales Volume                                                                        & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Percentage of Listings Sold                                                         & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Mean Time on Market                                                                 & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Mean Percentage of LIsting Price Received                                           & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Months Remaining of Inventory                                                       & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{FE0000} add this repo!!!}                                                                      &      &                   &            \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Leading, Lagging and Coincidental Indicators from the literature.}
\label{table:leadingLaggingIndiTable}
\end{table}
```

My problem is that the table is too long and goes beyond the border of the page.

[image]

Is it possible to split the table up via latex, so that it fits on two pages?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: use `longtable` (there is no need to use X columns from `tabularx` just replace them by `p{5cm}` or whatever width you need.

Comment: Please don't use `\bf` -- it's deprecated. Use `\textbf{...}` instead

Comment: Off-topic: Please consider to accept the answers to many of your questions here, so far you've accepted not a single one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `longtable` approach (the table is still too wide)
Here's the (simple) code (`booktabs` version below)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{p{4cm}|}l|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{ Indicator}                                                                     & \textbf{Source}                                                                                                               & \textbf{Time Period} & \textbf{Type} \\ \hline
\endhead  % This header will be repeated on every page with the table then
Dividend Yield                                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Short-term interest rates                                                           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
slope of the yield curve                                                            & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
interest rate spread(difference between the long-term and short-term interest rate) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Property Rents                                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
property yields                                                                     & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
GDP                                                                                 & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Lagging    \\ \hline
varEmployment and money supply                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
the three month Treasury Bill rate (TBIL)                                           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
the yield on 20-year gilts (GY20)                                                   & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
narrow money supply (M0)                                                            & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
broad money supply (M4) and the price on the FTSE 100 share index (SP100)           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
car registrations (CAR)                                                             & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
volume of retail sales (RS) and jobs vacancies (JOBV).                              & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Space market index                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
exports/import                                                                      & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
metropolitan area leading economic index                                            & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
job advertisements                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
the yield curve                                                                     & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
trade internationally currency exchange                                             & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
house starts                                                                        & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
average weekly                                                                      & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
hours in manufacturing                                                              & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
construction costs                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
construction activity                                                               & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Gilt yields                                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Car registrations                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Net lending to consumers                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Export orders                                                                       & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Volume of expected output                                                           & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Financial Surplus Deficit                                                           & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Consumer confidence                                                                 & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Stock of finished goods                                                             & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Real money supply                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Changes in inventories                                                              & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Consumer credit                                                                     & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Personal disposable income                                                          & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Industrial production                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Unit labour costs                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Gross trading profits                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
House building starts                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Yield curve                                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Manufacturing investment                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Real money supply                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Press recruitment ads.                                                              & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Private to total credit                                                             & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
New orders in manufacturing                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
FT All Share price Index                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Manufacturing employment                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Retail sales                                                                        & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Sales Volume                                                                        & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Percentage of Listings Sold                                                         & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Mean Time on Market                                                                 & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Mean Percentage of LIsting Price Received                                           & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
Months Remaining of Inventory                                                       & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   & Leading    \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{FE0000} add this repo!!!}                                                                      &      &                   &            \\ \hline
\caption{Leading, Lagging and Coincidental Indicators from the literature.}
\label{table:leadingLaggingIndiTable}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{Leading\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{4cm}}lQ{4cm}}
\toprule[2pt]
\textbf{Indicator}                                                                     & \textbf{Source}                                                                                                               & \textbf{Time Period} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{\textbf{Type}} \\ 
\midrule[1.5pt]
\endhead
Dividend Yield                                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
Short-term interest rates                                                           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
slope of the yield curve                                                            & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
interest rate spread(difference between the long-term and short-term interest rate) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
Property Rents                                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
property yields                                                                     & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
GDP                                                                                 & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   & Lagging    \\ \hline
varEmployment and money supply                                                      & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
the three month Treasury Bill rate (TBIL)                                           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
the yield on 20-year gilts (GY20)                                                   & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
narrow money supply (M0)                                                            & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
broad money supply (M4) and the price on the FTSE 100 share index (SP100)           & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
car registrations (CAR)                                                             & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
volume of retail sales (RS) and jobs vacancies (JOBV).                              & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000)~\cite{Brooks2000}                                                                        &                   &     \\ \hline
Space market index                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
exports/import                                                                      & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
metropolitan area leading economic index                                            & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
job advertisements                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
the yield curve                                                                     & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
trade internationally currency exchange                                             & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
house starts                                                                        & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
average weekly                                                                      & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
hours in manufacturing                                                              & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
construction costs                                                                  & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
construction activity                                                               & Cowley (2007)~\cite{Cowley2007}                                                                                          &                   &     \\ \hline
Gilt yields                                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Car registrations                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Net lending to consumers                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Export orders                                                                       & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Volume of expected output                                                           & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ 
Financial Surplus Deficit                                                           & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Consumer confidence                                                                 & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Stock of finished goods                                                             & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Real money supply                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Changes in inventories                                                              & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Consumer credit                                                                     & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Personal disposable income                                                          & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Industrial production                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Unit labour costs                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Gross trading profits                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
House building starts                                                               & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Yield curve                                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Manufacturing investment                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Real money supply                                                                   & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Press recruitment ads.                                                              & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Private to total credit                                                             & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
New orders in manufacturing                                                         & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
FT All Share price Index                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Manufacturing employment                                                            & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Retail sales                                                                        & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004)~\cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004}                                                   &                   &     \\ \hline
Sales Volume                                                                        & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   &     \\ \hline
Percentage of Listings Sold                                                         & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   &     \\ \hline
Mean Time on Market                                                                 & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   &     \\ \hline
Mean Percentage of LIsting Price Received                                           & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   &     \\ \hline
Months Remaining of Inventory                                                       & Miller and Sklarz (1986)~\cite{Miller1986}                                                                               &                   &     \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{FE0000} add this repo!!!}                                                                      &      &                   & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{}           \\ \hline
\caption{Leading, Lagging and Coincidental Indicators from the literature.}
\label{table:leadingLaggingIndiTable}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are more improvements possible: (Vertical spacing etc.), but that wasn't the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the `ltablex` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx` and some vertical padding for rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, ltablex, caption, ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}

\renewcommand\cite[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{ >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}S{X}|}m{3cm}|l|}
  \caption{Leading, Lagging and Coincidental Indicators from the literature.}
  \label{table:leadingLaggingIndiTable}%}
  \\\hline
  {\bfseries Indicator} & {\bfseries Source} & {\bfseries Time Period} & {\bfseries Type} \\ \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Leading, Lagging and Coincidental Indicators from the literature (continued).}\\[\abovecaptionskip]
  \hline
  {\bfseries Indicator} & {\bfseries Source} & {\bfseries Time Period} & {\bfseries Type} \\ \hline
  \endhead
  \endlastfoot
  \noalign{\smallskip}\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\em To be continued}
  \endfoot
  Dividend Yield & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Short-term interest rates & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  slope of the yield curve & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  interest rate spread (difference between the long-term and short-term interest rate) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Property Rents & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  property yields & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  GDP & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Lagging \\ \hline
  varEmployment and money supply & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  the three month Treasury Bill rate (TBIL) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  the yield on 20-year gilts (GY20) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  narrow money supply (M0) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  broad money supply (M4) and the price on the FTSE 100 share index (SP100) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  car registrations (CAR) & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  volume of retail sales (RS) and jobs vacancies (JOBV). & Brooks, Tsolacos and Lee (2000) \cite{Brooks2000} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Space market index & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  exports/import & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  metropolitan area leading economic index & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  job advertisements & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  the yield curve & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  trade internationally currency exchange & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  house starts & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  average weekly & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  hours in manufacturing & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  construction costs & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  construction activity & Cowley (2007) \cite{Cowley2007} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Gilt yields & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Car registrations & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Net lending to consumers & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Export orders & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Volume of expected output & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Financial Surplus Deficit & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Consumer confidence & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Stock of finished goods & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Real money supply & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Changes in inventories & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Consumer credit & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Personal disposable income & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Industrial production & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Unit labour costs & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Gross trading profits & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  House building starts & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Yield curve & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Manufacturing investment & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Real money supply & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Press recruitment ads. & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Private to total credit & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  New orders in manufacturing & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  FT All Share price Index & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Manufacturing employment & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Retail sales & Kyrstaloyianni, Matysiak and Tsolacos (2004) \cite{Kyrstaloyianni2004} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Sales Volume & Miller and Sklarz (1986) \cite{Miller1986} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Percentage of Listings Sold & Miller and Sklarz (1986) \cite{Miller1986} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Mean Time on Market & Miller and Sklarz (1986) \cite{Miller1986} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Mean Percentage of LIsting Price Received & Miller and Sklarz (1986) \cite{Miller1986} & & Leading \\ \hline
  Months Remaining of Inventory & Miller and Sklarz (1986) \cite{Miller1986} & & Leading \\ \hline
  {\color[HTML]{FE0000} add this repo!!!} & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]